# Proving $(-1)^n \cdot ( 3n-n^2 )/(4n^2 + 2)$ does not converge to $1/4$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Here's the problem I was assigned: Prove that

$$(-1)^n  {3n-n^2 \over 4n^2 + 2}\not\stackrel{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}{1\over 4}.$$

I understand that to prove a limit does not converge that it follows.

$$\exists \epsilon>0 \forall N\in\Bbb N\exists n (n\ge N \text{ and } |a(n)-L|) \ge\epsilon.$$

I am just confused as to what I would need to do to find an $\epsilon$ that makes

$$\left|(-1)^n \cdot{ 3n-n^2 \over 4n^2 + 2}-{1\over 4}\right| \ge \epsilon$$
for the cases when n is odd and when n is even.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that part of the product converges to $-1/4$. Additionally, there is an alternating sign, so the sequence will alternately approach $1/4$ and $-1/4$ every other term in the limit. The even terms converge to $-1/4$, so if you can prove this you can certainly bound part of the sequence away from $1/4$.

Additionally note that you can't find $\epsilon$ If $n$ is odd because none exists. That is fine, however, because we only need to show that there is always at least one term after any other term (or equivalently that there are infinitely many terms) that is at least $\epsilon$ away from $1/4$.

Comment: So let ε be 1/4 and let N ∈ ℕ. Let n be an even number greater than 3 such that n≥N. Then (3n - n²) < 0 and hence (-1)^n (3n - n²) / (4n² + 2) < 0, so |(-1)^n (3n - n²) / (4n² + 2) - 1/4| >= 1/4 = ε

since (-1)^n * (3n - n²) / (4n² + 2) doesn't converge to 1/4 when n is even, thus the sequence does not converge to 1/4.

would this be enough for my proof?

Comment: @Thomas nice, that's simpler than my suggestion.

Comment: would this be enough for my proof? I wouldn't need a case for when it is odd, correct?

Comment: @Thomas correct. Eventually every term would have to be near the limit for it to converge, and you've shown that doesn't happen.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for all the help, I appreciate it

Comment: @Thomas no problem.